# Incoming Data of bytes

Tags: java, android

I am dealing with a socket connection in which I send and then receive bytes. I have the socket code written and I can both send and receive bytes but there is a catch...

I am sending data within a language called Delphi and then receiving them in the android code. But I come into a bit of a problem.

In delphi a byte has a maximum value of 255 whereas in Android the maximum byte is 127. How would you get around this? Is there a way to use an unsigned byte? Should I use shorts instead of bytes?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a single byte you can cast it to a larger Java/Android primitive type to interpret it as an unsigned value by performing a bitwise & (AND) with an 8 bit mask. To write a value to the socket as an unsigned byte value use a larger primitive type to set the value, then cast this value to a byte to write to the socket. For example:

```
    short shortVal = 255;
    byte byteVal = (byte) shortVal;
    System.out.println("signed value = " + byteVal);
    shortVal = (short) (byteVal & 0xFF);
    System.out.println("unsigned value = " + shortVal);
```

Java/Android interprets the byte as a signed value (in this case, -1), but the 8 bits in the byte (11111111) are still the same as the least significant 8 bits in the short 255 (0000000011111111).

The same technique can be used with larger types (use int with 16 bit mask to interpret short as unsigned, long with 32 bit mask to interpret int as unsigned), but with multibyte values be careful to take into account the endianness of the network protocol and convert byte order if needed.